# Passing a parent_id via a form using the Ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rubygems

I am new to rails, I am using the ancestry gem and I am having trouble passing the parent_id via a form.

```
<% title "Messages" %>

<% for message in @messages %>

  <div class="message">
    <div class="created_at"><%= message.created_at.strftime("%B %d, %Y") %></div>   
    <div class="content">
      <%= message.content %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
      <%= link_to "Reply", new_message_path(:parent_id => message) %> |
      <%= link_to "Destroy", message, :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= semantic_form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p><%= f.select :content, [['United States','2'],['England','3'],['London','4']] %></p>
  <p><%= link_to "Reply", new_message_path(:parent_id => :content) %></p>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to assign a number (if the user selects 'United States' the number will be '2') to some variable and pass that variable when the user click reply as `<%= link_to "Reply", new_message_path(:parent_id => some_variable) %>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Rethink the problem. You probably want to do something like

```
<%= semantic_form_for @message do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>
  <p><%= f.select :parent_id, [['United States','2'],['England','3'],['London','4']] %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Reply" %></p>
<% end %>
```

And define needed routes.

Comment: Thanks, I tried a couple of variations on this and managed to get something working.